# Inverse Trigonometric Functions problem

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Hello mathematicians Today I am stuck with a rather simple problems.
$$y_1=\sin(\frac{1}{2} \arccos(\frac{4}{5}))$$

$$y_2=\cos(\frac{1}{2}\arccos(x))$$
I am required to simplify both of the above question but my problem is that there is $\frac{1}{2}\arccos(x)$ , I would have been easier if $\frac{1}{2}$ were not present ? how shall I solve them with that ? help ?

Comment: If only we had some kind of trigonometric formula for functions of half-angles... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\text{Let} \cos^{-1}0.8 = \theta\\ \cos \theta = 0.8 \\
1-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} = 0.8 \\
\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} = 0.1 \\
\sin\frac{\theta}{2} = \sqrt{0.1} \space \text{(think about why it is not negative)} \\
\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}0.8\right) = \sqrt{0.1}
$$
Hope you can do the other one too. (Use the same approach)

Comment: aha did so :) can you check my method?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing $$u=\frac{1}{2}\arccos(x)$$
$$2u=\arccos(x)$$
now taking $\cos$ of $2u$
$$cos(2u)=2cos^2(u)-1$$
$$cos^2(u)=\frac{1}{2}(cos(2u)+1)$$
$$cos(u)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(cos(2u)+1)}$$
$$cos(\frac{1}{2}\arccos(x))=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(x)+1}$$

Comment: That's correct.